# Magento 2: "Back" Link from View Order to Custom Grid

Tags: magento2, orders, order-grid, sales-order-view

I have a custom sales order grid that has a "view" link for each entry which takes the user to the standard Order View page.

Is there a way to make the "Back" link on the order view page go back to my custom grid, instead of the default Sales Order Grid?

EDIT: I still have the regular Sales Order Grid as well, so I need the link to return to whichever grid the user came from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by plugin.

Create this class:

```
<?php
namespace NameSpace\ModuleName\Plugin\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order;

use Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View as OrderView;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface;

class View
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface */
    protected $_urlBuilder;

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface */
    protected $_authorization;

    public function __construct(
        UrlInterface $url,
        AuthorizationInterface $authorization
    )
    {
        $this->_urlBuilder = $url;
        $this->_authorization = $authorization;
    }

    public function beforeSetLayout(OrderView $view)
    {
        $url = $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl('your_route', ['order_id' => $view->getOrderId()]);
        $view->updateButton('back', 'onclick', 'setLocation(\'' . $url . '\')');
    }
}
```

And in your `etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View">
        <plugin name="your_module_adminhtml_order_view_add_button" type="NameSpace\ModuleName\Plugin\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View" sortOrder="10" />
    </type>
</config>
```

This should work.

**UPDATE**

You could do this:

```
public function beforeSetLayout(OrderView $view) {
    $param = $view->getRequest()->getParam('redirect_back'); //you can even pass your route and use it in codntion then build the back url accordingly.
    if ( $param == '1') {
        $url = $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl('your_route', ['order_id' => $view->getOrderId()]);
        $view->updateButton('back', 'onclick', 'setLocation(\'' . $url . '\')');
    }
```

Now, in your custom grid build URL with the `redirect_back/1`. So your full grid URL should be like this:

`http://example.com/admin/sales/order/view/order_id/20/redirect_back/1/key/1c8e5cae74bb5d37038fbd3b79e4637caf6fd17112e40b51ef1bad63aef280b9/`

Comment: Thanks for this. It looks like it will change the back link in all cases? I should have been clearer, I also still have the regular Sales Order Grid as well, so basically I need the back link to return to whichever grid the user came from.

Comment: That will be a little tricky to achieve. Why not just adding a new button instead? You can add a new button from the same plugin.

Comment: I'd like to avoid confusing the user if possible, minimizing the number of available options.

Comment: Check my update.

Comment: It works flawlessly - perfect solution.